# Compare users last logon to 180 days ago

Tags: powershell-2.0

So far I have calculated both the date 180 days ago and the user's last login. But how do I get them to compare to each other?

```psh
$180_days_ago = (get-date) - (new-timespan - days 180)

GWmi Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | select @{label='LastLogon';expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon )}}
```

Comment: I know have this. It seems to work but not as effecient as I am hoping for.                             $180_days_ago = (get-date) - (new-timespan -days 180)
$180_days_ago_compare = get-date $180_days_ago -format G
$User_Last_Logon = GWmi Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | select @{label='LastLogon';expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon )}} | foreach {
if ($_.LastLogon -ge $180_days_ago_compare) {"Pass"} else {"Fail"}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date comparisons can be done like this:

```psh
$180_days_ago = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Where-Object {
  $_.LastLogon -and
  $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon) -gt $180_days_ago
}
```

That will give you the users that logged in less than 180 days ago. If you need all users with an indication whether their last login was before or after that cutoff you could do something like this:

```psh
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Where-Object {
  $_.LastLogon
} | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon) -gt $180_days_ago) {
    "{0}:`tOK" -f $_.Caption
  } else {
    "{0}:`tNot OK" -f $_.Caption
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep bleeding red on the ConvertToDateTime for some reason. Exception calling "ConvertToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Exception calling "ToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Specified argument was o
ut of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: dmtfDate""
At line:4 char:38
+   Where-Object { $_.ConvertToDateTime <<<< ($_.LastLogon) -gt $180_days_ago }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodRuntimeException

Comment: @JacoblovesRockstar You need to exclude empty `LastLogon` values. See updated answer.